# Golang & MySQL - Managing Connections

Tags: mysql, sql, go

I'm having trouble handling connections in a golang web app that uses MySQL.

In the tutorials I have seen the database interaction is all handled once, in the main function.

However, in the real world each http request will interact with the database - where should I keep sql.Open() and defer sql.Close()? Here is my code.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

var db *sql.DB

var pageTemplate = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("index.html"))

type Items []string

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql",
        "username:passwordl@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/databasename")
    checkErr(err)
    defer db.Close()
    _, err = db.Exec(
        `
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (
      item_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      item TEXT
    );
    `)
    checkErr(err)
    http.HandleFunc("/", mainHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}

func mainHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var item string
    var items Items
    stmt, err := db.Prepare("select item from items")
    checkErr(err)
    defer stmt.Close()
    rows, err := stmt.Query()
    checkErr(err)
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(&item)
        checkErr(err)
        items = append(items, item)
    }
    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        checkErr(err)
    }
    pageTemplate.Execute(w, items)
}

func checkErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

I get a runtime error on the line:

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("select item from items")
```

Persumably because the db isn't recognised outside of the main function. Should I instead have sql.Open() on each url Handler?

Apologies if the question is ambiguous.

Comment: sql.Open is really opening a connection pool.  the resulting db object is thread safe and can be used by your http handlers concurrently.  you generally will only call db.Close() before exiting your application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, you are redeclaring db inside your main function.

change:

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql",
```

to:

```
var err error
db, err = sql.Open("mysql",
```

Also consider reading about diffrent organizing methods when it comes to db access in your app. This is a great read: http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/organising-database-access

Comment: Aha! Thanks a lot for that and for the reading material. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In the

```
db, err := ...
```

statement the operator `:=` will define an new variable and hidde the global one with the same name.